# Openlayers 3 and Openlayers 2 together in same file

Tags: postgresql, openlayers, openstreetmap, openlayers-3, mapserver

Can i use openlayers 2 and openlayers 3 functions in same file? Although these functions are not same. For example using Openlayes.MapServer API of openlayers 2 in openlayers 3, as it is not present in openlayers 3. If not, how can i use Mapserver file with has 50 layers in Openlayers 3.

Thanks

Comment: No, you can't mix and match the APIs, OL3 is not backwards-compatible with OL2 and couldn't interact with it (at least without writing some plumbing code). As for the second issue, post it as a separate question (and it looks like it would be more suitable for http://gis.stackexchange.com but would probably be still closed as too broad and vague)

Comment: thanks for help! I will put another question for that.